# Can I change how LaTeX evaluates hyphenation?

Tags: hyphenation

At least for German-language documents (and especially when using microtype) LaTeX, to my taste, puts too much emphasis on preventing hyphenation.
Is there any parameter that can be changed so that, in favor of more consistent white spaces, more hyphenation is done?

Comment: That's a rather generic claim.  You'll get better answers if you provide a brief compilable example that demonstrates what you describe.  That will allow potential helpers to experiment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't claim anything. I'm just saying that I would like to have a different behaviour. My assumption was that there is probably some value that can be changed, like with `widowpenalty` for example.

Comment: The passage "LaTeX puts too much emphasis on preventing hyphenation" sounds like a claim to me... Please clarify what you mean by "more consistent white spaces",

Comment: try with `\hyphenpenalty=-100` choose a value you like, default is 50

Comment: In addition to decreasing `\hyphenpenalty` you probably want to set `\pretolerance=-1`.

Comment: More hyphenation doesn’t mean necessarily more consistent white space. In fact, if you allow every possible hyphenation point the spacing is usually much worse. Consider alternatives such as `microtype`.

Comment: @JavierBezos -- Sadly, the question itself says "(and especially when using microtype)".

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oops! I missed that. Anyway, my point is still (even more) valid.

Comment: @JavierBezos Unless TeX's line breaking algorithm is fundamentally flawed, this doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. It's like saying if you buy more tickets for the lottery, you will have worse chances of winning.

Comment: @JavierBezos What is "if you allow every possible hyphenation point" supposed to mean? Either a position within a word is a possible hyphenation point or it isn't, right? – Am I missing something?

Comment: @keth-tex TeX analyzes the whole paragraph and discards (orthographically valid) hyphenation points if the spacing isn’t even. A hyphen in the 1st line can lead to a bad spacing in the 4th line. By allowing every possible hyphenation point we are returning to a Word-like line composer. Note I’m not saying the rules cannot be fine tuned (depending on the font, the text width, the language, etc.), just that more hyphenation doesn’t mean necessarily more consistent white space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It just occurred to me that it's probably mostly that TeX tries to prevent hyphenation in consecutive lines. Is there a specific penalty value for this?

Comment: @JavierBezos This is probably a misunderstanding. Of course, more hyphenation does not automatically lead to more consistent whitespace. But more possible hyphenation points mean more possibilities and thus more flexibility. In many cases, there is obviously a trade-off between hyphenation and inconsistent whitespace. To me, "allowing" hyphenation points means that they are available as an option, not that they are actually used in any case.

Comment: If two consecutive lines are visually incompatible, in the sense explained
a minute ago, the current value of |\adjdemerits| is added to~$d$. If two consecutive lines end with discretionary breaks, the \doublehyphendemerits are added. And if the second-last line of the entire paragraph ends with
a discretionary, the |\finalhyphendemerits| are added. Plain \TeX\ sets
up the values |\adjdemerits=10000|, |\doublehyphendemerits=10000|,
and |\finalhyphendemerits=5000|. Demerits are in units of
``badness squared,''  (texbook)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What does "in the sense explained a minute ago" refer to?

Comment: @keth-tex it refers to an earlier paragraph "A line whose badness is 13 or more has a glue set ratio exceeding
50\%. We call such a line tight if its glue had to shrink,
loose if its glue had to stretch, and very loose
if it had to stretch so much that the badness is 100 or more. But if the
badness is 12 or less we say that the line is decent Two
adjacent lines are said to be **visually incompatible** if their
classifications are not adjacent, i.e., if a tight line is next to a
loose or very loose line, or if a decent line is next to a very loose one.
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The penalty for adding a hyphen `\hyphenpenalty` set to 50 by default (in plain and in latex) you can set this to say `\hyphenpenalty=-100` which will make it *prefer* to add hyphens (using negative values may be excessive, but you can experiment...)

You can also adjust the demerits that discourage consecutive lines with hyphens or hyphens on the penultimate line of the paragraph.

The TeXBook says:

> A line whose badness is 13 or more has a glue set ratio exceeding 50%. We call such a line tight if its glue had to shrink, loose if its glue had to stretch, and very loose if it had to stretch so much that the badness is 100 or more. But if the badness is 12 or less we say that the line is decent Two adjacent lines are said to be visually incompatible if their classifications are not adjacent, i.e., if a tight line is next to a loose or very loose line, or if a decent line is next to a very loose one.

> ...

> If two consecutive lines are visually incompatible, in the sense explained a minute ago, the current value of `\adjdemerits` is added to d. If two consecutive lines end with discretionary breaks, the `\doublehyphendemerits` are added. And if the second-last line of the entire paragraph ends with a discretionary, the `\finalhyphendemerits` are added. Plain TeX sets up the values `\adjdemerits=10000`, `\doublehyphendemerits=10000`, and `finalhyphendemerits=5000`. Demerits are in units of `badness squared,''